# Where's the textNode in the view coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, model-view-controller

[image: DB]

```rb
# controller
def index
  @teams = TeamMember.where(user: current_user)
end
```

```rb
# view
<%= @teams.each do |t| %>
  <h2><%= t.project.name %></h2>
  <p>Where's the line below this coming from?</p>
  <!-- what's happening here? -->
<% end %>
```

The result in the browser looks as follows. It returns @projects as a string. Where is this coming from and how do I remove it?

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ERB](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html)

> You trigger ERB by using embeddings such as <% %>, <% -%>, and <%= %>. The <%= %> tag set is used when you want output.

You have used `<%= %>` for looping projects and the block form of `Array#each` returns the original `Array object`, which is why it prints the projects result at the end.

you have to use `<% %>` for `@projects.each do |p|` instead of `<%= %>`

```
# view
<% @projects.each do |p| %>
  <h2><%= p.name %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Team member Model**

```
 class TeamMember < ApplicationRecord
    
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project

 end
```

**User Model**

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :team_members

 end
```

**Project Model**

```
 class Project < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :team_members

 end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  @teams = current_user.team_members
end
```

**View**

```
<% @teams.each do |t| %> // Remove '=' from the loop itereation
  <h2> <%= t.project.name %> </h2>
<% end %>
```